# Closing vim Conque after loging off

Tags: vim

i've been using http://code.google.com/p/conque/ for Vim, working properly, and i've been assigning Ctrl+M to run :ConqueTermSplit bash on .vimrc using these command:

```
 map <C-M> :ConqueTermSplit bash<CR>
```

is there a way to close current conque split-screen/buffer without having type :q or :bd before/after bash program is terminated? (normally i quit bash using ctrl+d)

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation:](http://code.google.com/p/conque/wiki/Usage#2.1_General_Usage)

> **3.1.7 Close buffer when program exits**
>
> If you want your terminal buffer to be closed and permanently deleted when the program running inside of it exits, set this option to 1. Otherwise the buffer will become a simple text buffer after the program exits, and you can edit the program output in insert mode.
>
> ```
> let g:ConqueTerm_CloseOnEnd = 0
> ```

Comment: i don't know why, but it doesn't work.. i've add let g:ConqueTerm_CloseOnEnd = 1 on .vimrc, restart vim, press ctrl+M then ctrl+D, but it still doesn't automatically exit, i must type :q to remove conque buffer

Comment: I don't use that plugin so I can't really help you further, sorry.

Comment: Try deleting the line 758 on conque_term.vim, then `let g:ConqueTerm_CloseOnEnd = 1` should work. I've submitted a patch: http://goo.gl/XYoGH